# EF6 Linq - How to create an filter expression equivalent to "where(List == null || List.Contains(obj))"?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to do the following (SelectedIdCollection is List and cb.Id is int) -

```
db.Items.Where(cb => (SelectedIdCollection == null || SelectedIdCollection.Contains(cb.Id)))
```

Basically, if `SelectedIdCollection` is null then return everything, if it is not null then filter by it.

But it throws the following error -

> *An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code. Cannot
>   compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are
>   supported.*

Is there any other way of writing this where condition?

Comment: How about using `if` (conditional `Where`)

Comment: Does `SelectedIdCollection?.Contains(cb.Id) ?? true` work?

Comment: @PatrickHofman That won't compile.  There is no expression for the null propagation operator.

Comment: `db.Items.AsEnumerable().Where(cb => (SelectedIdCollection == null || SelectedIdCollection.Contains(cb.Id)))`

Comment: `IQueryable <Item> itemsQuery = db.Items; if(SelectedIdCollection ! = null && SelectedIdCollection.Any ()) { itemsQuery = itemsQuery.Where(cb => (SelectedIdCollection.Contains(cb.Id))) }; var items = itemsQuery.ToList();`

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, this works, thank you. But does it load all entities before the Where() executes? Any performance considerations?

Comment: @Achilles Yes, it would, making that a horrible solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is being thrown because you are comparing a runtime variable (`SelectedIdCollection != null`), and EF doesn't know how to translate that into SQL.

Can you do something like this instead?

```
var items = db.Items.AsQueryable();

if(SelectedIdCollection != null)
{
   items = items.Where(cb => SelectedIdCollection.Contains(cb.Id));
}

if(date1 != null)
{
   items = items.Where(cb => cb.Date1 == date1);
}
```

This will potentially be faster in SQL as well, because the query planner might choose different indexes if it doesn't need to read all the columns to filter.

Comment: Yes, I could but eventually there are going to be more fields in that filters - .Where(cb => (amount < 0 || cb.amount == amount) && (date1 == null ? cb.Date1 == date1)) etc etc.

Comment: You can chain as many `.Where` as you want, so that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Like - 

if(SelectedIdCollection != null) {
   items = items.Where(cb => SelectedIdCollection.Contains(cb.Id)); } if(amount < 0) {items.Where(cb => cb.Amount = amount);} and so on in separate if clauses?

Comment: Updated answer. Just build the `Where` calls on top of each-other -- EF will produce a proper query.

Comment: Thank you, this works, I didn't realize that the query can be built incrementally so that not all conditions need to go in the same Where().

Answer (score 4):

Since `SelectedIdCollection` is a variable captured from outside your expression, you can deal with it being `null` before making the expression, and then treat it as non-null:

```
var getEverything = SelectedIdCollection==null;
var targetCollection = SelectedIdCollection ?? new int[0];
var res = db.Items.Where(cb => getEverything || targetCollection.Contains(cb.Id));
```

Now `targetCollection` is guaranteed to be non-`null`, and `getEverything` flag covers the condition that requires selecting everything from the database.